# Visual C++ 11 cannot find Boost unit_test_framework library in CMake generated project

Tags: visual-c++, boost, cmake

I have a C++ project using CMake and Boost that compiles/links under Linux without any problems. I'm working towards porting this to Windows via Visual C++ 2012.

My CMake configuration is as follows:

```
set(BOOST_ROOT ${DEPENDENCY_DIR}/boost/)
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS   ON)
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME    OFF)
find_package(Boost 1.53 COMPONENTS system date_time chrono serialization filesystem program_options random thread regex unit_test_framework)

message(STATUS "Boost Version:" ${Boost_VERSION})
message(STATUS "Boost Include Dirs:" ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})
message(STATUS "Boost Libraries:")
foreach(lib ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
        message(STATUS ${lib})
endforeach()

include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})
```

and I'm using `target_link_libraries` with `${Boost_LIBRARIES}` in my targets. Also above `message` commands show all found files without any problem.

Moreover required libraries show `libboost_unit_test_framework-vc110-mt-gd-1_53.lib` as it should be.

[image: screenshot of library dependencies]

However, when I build one of the targets, I get

```
2>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'boost_unit_test_framework-vc110-mt-gd-1_53.lib'
```

I removed another Boost library and from the error it seems the linker is able to find others. (like `chrono` or `serialization`.) But the error message is a bit different. The filename has *lib* in front of it.

```
2>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_serialization-vc110-mt-gd-1_53.lib'
```

Why does VC++ looks for a file prefixed with **boost** and not **libboost** for unit_test_framework?

Comment: Did you try `add_definitions(-DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB)` to disable [boost's auto-linking feature](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/config/doc/html/boost_config/boost_macro_reference.html#boost_config.boost_macro_reference.macros_for_libraries_with_separate_source_code)

Answer (score 0):

Alright, check for two things:

- Ensure the file actually exists in the give path, and you have read permission.
- Ensure you are using 32-bit .LIB for 32-bit build, and 64-bit .LIB for 64-bit LIB.

Comment: I checked both of these. BTW, when I remove that particular unit_test_framework dependency, it compiles targets which don't depend on this particular library.